# SQL Server : increment INT column using variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to insert an order column into some records, based on another field. Normally not a problem in MySQL, but in SQL Server I can't quite understand the syntax here.

This is what I have:

```
DECLARE @a int
SET @a = 1

UPDATE tablename 
SET order_position = @a:=@a+1  
WHERE table_id = xxx
```

But part of me thinks this is going down the route of a function/procedure as opposed to a one hit `UPDATE` query.

Sorry, but I wrote this as a MySQL database person, not familiar with variables with SQL Server so could be a little wrong.

I need to run this on a load of records one by one, and I want the order_position column to be 1-7 (where there are 7 records), etc..

Thanks, Chris

Comment: What field is the order based on?

Comment: Well I need to order the results before I update them, so they are in the right order. We'll call it 'fieldsort' for the purpose of this exercise.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this code:

```
DECLARE @a int
SET @a = 1
UPDATE tablename SET order_position = @a, @a=@a+1  WHERE table_id = xxx
```

You are trying to do a double assignment which is the issue.  `"order_position = @a:=@a+1"` has 2 interpretations, one you know and the other is that the result of incrementing a, that it succeeded is what should go in the order_position value.

Comment: Yes, although after doing this I realised that the order of the rows updated may not be in the right order anyway, so I'm going to need to do a function of some sort. But good to know.

Comment: I have an extended question, I have a table with millions of records with "ArticleId, ViewCount". Every time a user view a article I update viewCount for that article. There could be 200 requests for view article at a time, that means 200 update queries on the Count table. Will there be any performance issues I should cover for? is there any other best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Multiple updates could lead to deadlocks and other race conditions that could be a problem. Snapshots can be a workaround for slow reads but would create other issues still.

Comment: do you know why did not work after update database to 2017(140) ?

Answer (score 6):

Separate the variable incrementing from the field update.

```
DECLARE @a int
SET @a = 1
UPDATE tablename 
SET order_position = @a
   ,@a = @a + 1  
WHERE table_id = xxx
```

Coming from MySQL you may be overlooking a great tool for this task, `ROW_NUMBER()`.

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a number to each row in a table:

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ....  ORDER BY .... )
FROM Table
```

`PARTITION BY` indicates a grouping for numbering, ie there will be a '1' for each combination of fields used in the `PARTITION BY`, and they will of course be ordered from 1-n based on the `ORDER BY` clause.